# SharePoint Custom List View Based on User

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list and I need the list item to be displayed based on user's permission level. Say for example, I am adding a new list item and it should only be visible to me. Users who have **"FullControl"** access should see all the items.

Comment: Explain the scenario in detail, your question doesn't help understand your situation. Do you want users who don't have Full Control to see only Items created by them. Or you want something else ?

Comment: Yes, I want the users who dont have full-control should see only the items created by them.